# Comparing a png image with an image in app

Tags: android, robotium

I am trying to create a test case using robotium. What I want to do is compare an image file i-e an png image to the image in application I know the resource id of the image-view in application R.id.Progrom_Play.

```
ImageView ff = (ImageView) solo.getView(com.media.R.id.program_play_button);
boolean z = ff.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.recording_gray).getConstantState());
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem with your code?

Comment: I am getting error in the second line of  code .I want to compare 2 images files/drawable .Is there any alternate way in which I can compare 2 iamges